# Local copy of network share for performance reasons?

Tags: windows, sync, network-shares

At the company I work for we have a few graphic designers, and one of them works in a different country. Their internet connection speed is very poor, which has a large negative effect considering many of the files they work on are 10MB+. All the graphic designers share a Network Share so that they all have access to each others work.

I've been asked to improve the speed with which the remote designer can access files. My idea is to have some kind of mirroring of the file share at their location so they can access it at high speed. I liked the look of DFSR but unfortunately we don't have any servers in the designer's country and DFSR seems to be a server-only feature. I need a solution that will work on the user's computer.

I looked into Windows' Sync Center/Offline Files, but it's designed to mirror folders so they can be accessed when no connection is available, and by default it doesn't do anything to improve performance. It has a Transparent Caching feature that can be enabled, but this only helps when a file has been opened in the past and has not changed since it was last opened. Additionally it provides no performance benefits for write operations. I need a solution that allows the user to fully interact with their local copy and have changes synced bidirectionally to/from the network share.

I heard good things about DSynchronize by Dimio, but when I tried it out I had problems. When I set it up it immediately started to try to delete all files on the network share! I cancelled it and tried to turn on "Don't delete any files" but this option is not available when the sync is set to Bidirectional. I feel it shouldn't have to be said, but I need a solution that will not delete all my files.

Has anyone set up something similar in the past? How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

YM

Comment: You should edit your question because software recommendation is off topic here. Just ask "how to". If You need software, You should post here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Are the graphic designers in the same network, or do they share their resources over the internet?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my post. The remote graphic designer uses a VPN to connect to the network that the other designers are on.

Comment: Idea: how about making a sync folder (ex. *dropbox*)? They could upload their work inside a share and the graphic designers computer would synchronize the changes.

Comment: Something worth trying is adding an exemption on the artist's system's antivirus for that folder. I once had to [trace a similar issue](http://superuser.com/q/898310/10165), and it was almost magical. Do the files change often? Do you need bidirectional sync? How does security need to be? You could run something like owncloud if you need it to be self hosted, and an amusing way to handle stuff like this might be git.

Comment: @Divin3 Possibly, I'd prefer something self-hosted though.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There don't seem to be any antivirus-related problems. When files are being actively worked on they change frequently. Bidirectional sync is vital, as I need all designers to be able to receive changes made by other designers. OwnCloud looks interesting, I might give that a go. Git is a possibility too. Ideally I'd like a 100% clientside solution though, one that just uses the existing network share.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a hard problem to solve.

I've not used it, but on paper it looks like [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org) could do this for you.  Looking into this though, [it does not have great support for a Windows server.](https://owncloud.org/blog/owncloud-server-8-1-will-not-support-windows-as-server-platform-natively/)  - which means using Linux - either on bare metal or as a VM for the file server.

Answer (score 1):

With windows offline sync, you can go into "offline" mode even when you're online.  That allows you to interact with the folder locally and get local performance.  You can then go "online" at the end of the day and get updates synchronized.

I think that would give you the flexibility you seek.

You should see a "Work Offline" / "Work Online" option in the toolbar of Windows Explorer when you're inside the shared folder.